# python ast.literal_eval throwing malformed string error given "datetime.datetime.now()"

Tags: python

I need to evaluate the string before assigning it, so I am using eval. But I read eval is not good to use and instead use ast.literal_eval. But when using ast.literal_eval, I am getting malformed string error.

```
import datetime
x = eval('datetime.datetime.now()')
print x
```

Result:

```
2017-12-29 11:15:22.191322
```

Code with Ast

```
import datetime
import ast
x = ast.literal_eval('datetime.datetime.now()')
```

Result:

> Malformed String

Comment: `literal_eval` is not a magical unicorn. There are limits to its uses. The only thing it can parse is string representations of data structures, not expressions like this.

Comment: `datetime.datetime.now()` is not a literal. `literal_eval()` is only supposed to evaluate literals -- this is a security measure, ensuring that code can't be sneaked in in places where data is expected.

Comment: Err, my bad. I did mean that function only.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy : In my scenario to evalute, I can use only eval ??

Comment: @gmrli, ...*can* use `eval` and *can't* use `literal_eval`, certainly. "can only use eval" is a bit too strong -- there are other approaches, even if they're not generalizable or practical.

Comment: @gmrli, ...basically, a "literal" is a value that can be directly expressed in a language, without needing to call a function / instantiate an object / etc.

Comment: This sounds like it might be an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem). You want to do something (X) and `eval`ing a string may be a way to do it (Y), and you're asking for a better way to do Y (like `literal_eval`). That specific alternative solution doesn't work, but since you haven't actually described what X is (that is, why you are `eval`ing a string in the first place) we can't offer any suggestions for different approaches that might be better at solving the problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[`ast.literal_eval`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/ast.html) document clearly says:

> Safely evaluate an expression node or a string containing a Python literal or container display.
>
> The string or node provided **may *only* consist of the following Python literal structures: strings, bytes, numbers, tuples, lists, dicts, sets, booleans, and None.**